# Prevent jTextArea from adding [ when appending arraylist

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a `JTextArea` that appends an `ArrayList<String>`. This works well enough. But its also adding [ characters in as well. How can I prevent this?

```
jTextArea1.append(myarraylist.toString() + COMMA_DELIMITER + "\n");
```

Comment: What is the value of `COMMA_DELIMITER`?  Oh never mind.. For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: That's going to be difficult its only allowing me to post a few characters at a time! I trim it down and it still insists its too long?

Comment: *".. its only allowing me to post a few characters at a time!"*  Rubbish!  An MCVE should be shorter than 200 lines of code.  An MCVE for *this problem* could be done with less than 70 LOC. I personally have posted questions with code that was near on 650 LOC.  Do you see why your claim does not seem plausible?

Comment: `it still insists its too long? ` - then is it not a SSCCE. It take 3-4 lines of code to create a Jframe. Another couple of lines of code to create a JTextArea and add it to the frame. It will take 3-4 lines of code to create an ArrayList and add a couple of Strings to the List. It will then take 3-4 lines of code to create the loop using the append method. That is about 20 lines of code for the SSCCE. Unless you learn to simplify problem you won't learn to problem solve.

Answer (score 3):

You can't append the toString() of an ArrayList, unless you like the exact formatting of the toString() method of the ArrayList.

If you want custom formatting of the data you need to add each element separately by iterating through each element in the ArrayList. Something like:

```
for (Object text: myArrayList)
{
    jTextArea1.append(text.toString() + "...");
}
```

Comment: @RobD, then don't forget to "accept" the answer so others know the problem has been solved. You have posted multiple questions in the forum and have not yet accepted any answers.